# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'PAY_TYPE' of null"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to display the **PAY_TYPE** from **callback_details** by using JSON.parse() to convert string into object but I tried and keeps getting the error as question title.

My code:

```
<td class="text-xs-left">{{props.item.payment_method}}<br>({{JSON.parse(props.item.callback_details).PAY_TYPE}})</td>
```

data():

```
data(){
return{
  loading: false,
  startDate: '',
  endDate: '',
  startMenu: false,
  endMenu: false,
  pagination:{
    rowsPerPage: -1
  },
  orders:[],
  payment:[],
  list1: [],
  list2: [],
  payment_headers:[
    { text: this.$translate('merchant'),     value: 'merchant' },
    { text: this.$translate('shop_owner'),    value: 'shop_owner', sortable: false },
    { text: this.$translate('platform_fee'),      value: 'platformFee', sortable: false },
    { text: this.$translate('total_earning'),      value: '', sortable: false }
  ],
  details_headers:[
    { text: this.$translate('shop_name'),    value: 'shop_name' },
    { text: this.$translate('date'),    value: 'created' },
    { text: this.$translate('buyer_yippi'),    value: 'yippiWallet' },
    { text: this.$translate('purchase'),       value: 'yippsAmount', sortable: false },
    { text: this.$translate('payment_type'),    value: 'payment_method', sortable: false},
    { text: this.$translate('platform_fee'),      value: 'platformFee', sortable: false },
    { text: this.$translate('earning_fee'),      value: '', sortable: false }
  ],
  json:{},
  count: 0,
  tableSettingsOne: {
            descending: true,
            sortBy: null,
            rowsPerPage: 25,
            pageSizes: [
                {"text":"5","value":5},
                {"text":"10","value":10},
                {"text":"25","value":25},
                {"text":"50","value":50},
                {"text":"All","value":-1}
            ]
    },
    tableSettingsTwo: {
            descending: true,
            sortBy: null,
            rowsPerPage: 25,
            pageSizes: [
                {"text":"5","value":5},
                {"text":"10","value":10},
                {"text":"25","value":25},
                {"text":"50","value":50},
                {"text":"All","value":-1}
            ]
    }
}
```

},

What I want to display is the **PAY_TYPE** from **callback_details**:

```
callback_details: "{"TXN_ID":"262439","PAY_TYPE":"VISAMASTER","STATUS_INFO":"2003267b9029b3b"}
```

AND I'm getting these errors:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'PAY_TYPE' of null"

TypeError: Cannot read property 'PAY_TYPE' of null
```

Anyone of you know to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: where is 'props.item' defined?

Comment: `JSON.parse(props.item.callback_details)` - that's likely incorrect. Verify the values of `props`, `props.item`, and `props.item.callback_details`, in order. Update the usage of the result of the `JSON.parse(..)` call [possibly even eliminating it] accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra quotation mark on `callback_details`:

```
callback_details: {"TXN_ID":"262439","PAY_TYPE":"VISAMASTER","STATUS_INFO":"2003267b9029b3b"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  callback_details: JSON.parse('{"TXN_ID":"262439","PAY_TYPE":"VISAMASTER","STATUS_INFO":"2003267b9029b3b"}');
```

And

```
<td class="text-xs-left">{{props.item.payment_method}}<br>({{props.item.callback_details.PAY_TYPE}})</td>
```